# Remove /index.html from url for static site

Tags: google-cloud-storage, rsync, cp, gsutil

I have a static site on google-cloud-storage bucket.

I rsync my site to the storage bucket with:

`args: ["-m", "-h", "Content-Encoding:gzip", "rsync", "-c", "-r", "./folder", "gs://mysite.com"]`

I have set in my cloud bucket for website config:

`/index.html`

This results in:

`mysite.com/category/index.html`

And from this I want to remove the `index.html`, so I tried in addition to above `args` in a second line, the following:

`args: ["-h", "Content-Type:text/html", "cp", "./folder/*/index.html", "gs://mysite.com/*"]`

But this second args did not work.

How to write the second `args` so that the `index.html` is removed from the URL in `mysite.com/category/index.html`?

Answer (score 0):

The second args are probably working, the thing is that you are using [`cp`](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/commands/cp) which copies files, so you are just uploading the `index.html` file again.

If you want to remove the `index.html` you have to use [`rm`](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/commands/rm):

`args: ["-h", "Content-Type:text/html", "rm", "gs://mysite.com/category/index.html"]`

Comment: this removes all files with /index.html that I uploaded earlier. How to remove just the /index.html but keep the files that have that extension?

Comment: I'm not understanding what you are trying to say, you can only have one 'index.html' file per folder, which other files are being removed? 
I have tried the args I posted and they just remove the only 'index.html' file you have in the 'category' folder, can you specify a bit more on what is happening?